# Can adjectives starting with a- precede the noun?

Tags: adjectives, word-order, prefixes

The prefix *a-* holds many entries in the dictionary. I am considered with one of them:

> **a-** *prefix*
>
> to; toward: aside | ashore.
>
> • in a specified state or manner: asleep | aloud.
>
> • in the process of (an activity): a-hunting.
>
> • on: afoot.
>
> • in: nowadays.

To my native ear it seems adjectives formed in such a way cannot precede the noun they describe. A few Google Ngram searches cannot prove or deny this sense, but they do indicate that these adjectives are much more likely to follow than to precede the noun.

This sense could just be because I am more accustomed to this prefix forming adverbs instead of adjectives.

**Can adjectives formed with the *a-* prefix (*in a specified state or manner*) precede the adjective they describe? If not, what is the rule?**

Comment: Predicate adjectives cannot precede the noun. And many predicate adjectives start with this *a-* prefix.

Comment: The prefix a is derived from various words/prepositions and they were attached to a noun to form an adjective. For example, [asleep](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=asleep&allowed_in_frame=0)  is from Old English *on sleep* and you can't use "on seelp child" in contemprorary English.

Comment: @Rathony, to be fair, you can't say "child on sleep" in contemporary English either, but you can say "child asleep" even if it is more poetic

Comment: It's probably because these are mostly adverbs.

Comment: @Azor-Ahai I did consider that, but some are strictly adjectives (right now I can only think of the fiery examples *aglow* and *ablaze*. I think though that the fact that most such words are adverbs might influence how we treat those that are not

Comment: Give examples of sentences with these words and we can only then tell you which are good and which bad.

Comment: Have you read this? http://english.stackexchange.com/a/111662/2085

Comment: @tchrist No I had not. Thank you. It is difficult to search for *a-* because any result with *a* in it appears.

Answer (score 1):

No, those modifiers have to follow what they modify, apparently.  You yourself have given the rule.  Congratulations on finding it.

Comment: It's because they used to be prepositional phrases.

Comment: @tchrist, That might explain why they didn't used to be before what they modify, but how does it explain why they aren't now?

Comment: Because we got used to it?

Answer (score 1):

The answer, which should surprise no one, is that English is more flexible than the pronouncements of rule makers. Here is but one example for *asleep* from [*Wesley's Wars*](https://books.google.com/books?id=cQ-FBGtp1MYC&pg=PA42&dq=%22asleep%20man%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjbxp_rtYfRAhWF7CYKHRUCC-k4ChDoAQgpMAM#v=onepage&q=%22asleep%20man%22&f=false) by J. Robert Ewbank:

> Christians know this blind or spiritually **asleep man** to really be a servant of sin.